# Long mat for shower?

Tags: shower, materials

I am searching for long (10m) pvc mat for the dressing room before big shower room and sauna.
The mat is two layered. The lower layer maximises air while the top layer is for endurance.
I saw such a mat in one hotel yesterday and want similar for my summer house.

I searched unsuccessfully in AliExpress.

How can you call such a mat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **How can you call such a mat?**

The general name for a long thin protective mat is a **runner**.

[image]

Walmart "Vinyl Runner".

Comment: That is a right direction! Some appropriate other keywords are **floor runners rugs waterproof**. I also used **outdoor** as the keyword to emphasise that the product is made of full of plastic. However, I have not precisely found such a mat made two plastic components where the lower component maximises the air circulation below.